# Chrome extension: Send message from web page to chrome extension with out open extension from chrome://apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have created a chrome extension which support native messaging. Extension is working fine as expected, run extension using chrome://apps. Now I tried to trigger extension from web page, it work only when I open my extension from chrome://apps but if I don't open extension it didn't work, while extension is installed in chrome.

mainifest.json:

```
{

  "name": "Native Messaging Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*","https://*/*"], "js": ["contentscript.js"], "run_at": "document_start"}]
}
```

Content Script:

```
document.addEventListener("hello", function(data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("test");
})
```

Background.js

```
 var port = null;
    var getKeys = function(obj){
       var keys = [];
       for(var key in obj){
          keys.push(key);
       }
       return keys;
    }


    function appendMessage(text) {
      document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>";
    }

    function updateUiState() {
      if (port) {
        document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function sendNativeMessage() {
      message = {"text": document.getElementById('input-text').value};
      port.postMessage(message);
      appendMessage("Sent message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
    }

    function onNativeMessage(message) {
      appendMessage("Received message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
    }

    function onDisconnected() {
      appendMessage("Failed to connect: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      port = null;
      updateUiState();
    }

    function connect() {
      var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
      appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")
      port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
      port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
      port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
      updateUiState();
    }
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert("message received");

        var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
      appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")
      port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
      port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
      port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);

    });


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('connect-button').addEventListener(
          'click', connect);
      document.getElementById('send-message-button').addEventListener(
          'click', sendNativeMessage);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage("test");
      updateUiState();
    });
```

page.HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
    var go = function() {
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('hello');
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:go();">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You did not declare your [`background` script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) in your *manifest.json*. For instance: `"background": {"scripts": ["Background.js"]},`. It's not loaded just because it's called *Background.js*.

Comment: Thanks Makyen, I added backgroud.js also removed "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  } from mainifest.js. It worked then without loading extension from chrome://app.